# Proof that a quasicategory is equivalent to the homotopy coherent nerve of a simplicial category

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, simplicial-categories

On the abstract of [a paper by Emily Riehl and Dominic Verity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09834.pdf), it is stated that

> Every quasicategory arises as a the homotopy coherent nerve of a simplicial category up to equivalence.

Where can one find a proof of this statement?

---

On motivation for the question, HTT 4.2.4.1 would then imply that any colimit in a quasicategory could be computed as a homotopy colimit of a diagram $F\colon\mathbf{J}\rightarrow\mathbf{C}$, where $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are simplicial categories.

Comment: (I tried (but failed) to find such a proof in HTT, the cited paper, and Categorical Homotopy Theory by Riehl.)

Comment: HTT.2.2.5.1....

Comment: @DylanWilson Thank you for the pointer (and for the comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321105/how-should-one-approach-reading-spectral-algebraic-geometry-by-lurie) (I was unsure if I should answer there since MathOverflow has this strange no-thanks-in-comments policy (and I didn't have anything to add there besides a thank you)))! I couldn't see how the statement in the question would follow from HTT.2.2.5.1 (could you please elaborate on this?), but, while searching in other sources, I found a construction in...

Comment: ...Section 15.3 of Joyal's [Notes on Quasi-Categories](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/IMA/Joyal.pdf).

Comment: The "summary version" of this comparison is in HTT section 1.1.5, with reference of key proofs to sections 2.2.4 and 2.2.5.

Comment: Doesn’t it follow from the definition of “Quillen equivalence”? Apply N to a fibrant replacement of C(S).

Comment: @DylanWilson Oh, I didn't know about that characterization of Quillen equivalences! (I just knew the Quillen-adjunction-such-that-derived-functors-give-an-equivalence-of-homotopy-categories definition) Would you consider posting this as an answer so that I can accept it? Also, thank you!

Comment: @DylanWilson Following your explanation, I have posted an answer as _CW_. If you prefer answering the question yourself, I shall promptly delete the second answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, we should have made this more clear. One proof appears as Theorem 7.2.2 in our previous paper in this series, [The comprehension construction](https://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/comprehension.pdf). As suggested by others, it follows from a suitably defined Yoneda embedding (which is hard to construct in the ∞-categorical setting).

Explicitly we show that a quasi-category B is equivalent to the homotopy coherent nerve of the full simplicial subcategory of the slice category qCat/B spanned by the right fibrations B/b -> B for each vertex b in B. Because the only objects we consider here are right fibrations the hom-spaces between two such in qCat/B are automatically Kan complexes.

The hard part of this is defining the map of quasi-categories from B to the homotopy coherent nerve, which by adjunction we construct as a simplicially enriched functor indexed by the "homotopy coherent realization" of B.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a quasicategory. Using a version of the Yoneda lemma for quasicategories, Joyal constructs, in Section 15.3 of his [Notes on Quasi-Categories](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/IMA/Joyal.pdf), a simplicial category $\overline{\mathbf{C}}$ such that $\mathrm{N}_\Delta(\overline{\mathbf{C}})$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

The result is actually valid for *any* simplicial set.

**Lemma.** If

[image]

is a Quillen equivalence, then the composition
$$A\xrightarrow{\eta_A}G(F(A))\xrightarrow{G\left(P_{F(A)}\right)}G(P(F(A)))$$
is a weak equivalence, where $P(A)$ denotes the fibrant replacement of an object $A\in\mathscr{A}$.

*Proof.* See Lemma 3.5.2 of [these notes](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~apatotski/7400-notes-2015.pdf) for a proof.

Now, HTT 2.2.5.1 states that $(\mathfrak{C},\mathrm{N}_\Delta)$ gives a Quillen equivalence:

[image]

The above lemma then implies that given a cofibrant object in $\mathit{sSets}_\mathrm{Joyal}$ (that is, any simplicial set) $S_\bullet$, we have a weak equivalence
$$S_\bullet\rightarrow\mathrm{N}_\Delta\left(P(\mathfrak{C}[S_\bullet])\right).$$

In particular, if $\mathscr{C}$ is a quasicategory, then $Q(\mathfrak{C}[\mathscr{C}]) $ is a simplicial category whose homotopy coherent nerve is equivalent to $\mathscr{C}$.